What is Laplace transform of $t^af(t)$ if Laplace transform of $f(x)$ is $F$.
What is the Laplace transform of $t^af(t),a>0$ if the Laplace transform of $f(x)$ is given to be $F(s)$. By definition, it should be like this:
$$\mathcal{L}\{t^a f(t)\}(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^a f(t) e^{-st} \, dt$$
Wha after that? Can we express it in terms of $F(s)$ only? If it is a known result, please provide the references.
Here , it is given in terms of derivative of the Laplace transform positive integer $a$.

The same formula as with integer $a$ is valid, but you will have to consider fractional derivative of $F$ instead.
